# Write to SD Card on Platform Uno

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, android-sdcard, uno-platform

I am wondering how to write to a SD Card on Platform Uno?
I have managed to write to the normal storage, but how do I ask for write permission and write on a SD card on Android?

Kind Regards,
JaFu0815

Comment: Which level of Android API are you using ?

Comment: Im using API level 26

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After Android 6.0 (API level 23), you should requests the [runtime permissions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) and the [official doucument](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

and you also could to use the nugetpackage **Plugin.Permissions** to request runtime permissions (StoragePermission)

refer to [Plugin.Permissions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)